# makefile and multiple file C++ template issue

Tags: c++, templates, makefile

I've got a C++ template class split into two files using #include directive as suggested in this link --> [Templates spread across multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039/templates-spread-across-multiple-files)

For both files I've used the standard naming *.h and *.cpp.
In the makefile I've included the *.h one since - as I understand it - both files split in such way are in fact one from the compiler point of view. I've set the same compilation options as in case of compiling a ususal *.cpp file.

However, when I try to compile it through makefile i get the following error:

```
Stos.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I've read somewhere that it might be due to the fact that I compile *.h file. I do not know what should I do instead.

Thank you for your help.

#### EDIT

I am posting the makefile itself to make matter more clear. Please, excuse me that the names are not in English, however in this case this shouldn't be a problem. I've updated the error message so that it fits the makefile.

Because of suggestions here, I've already changed names for template files from *.h and *.cpp mentioned above to *.hpp and *.tpp.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -pedantic -W
COMP= $(CC) $(CFLAGS)

program: Graf.o wgraf.o wnazwe.o menu.o Stos.o TabDyn.o komunikaty.o main.o
    $(CC) Graf.o wgraf.o wnazwe.o menu.o Stos.o TabDyn.o komunikaty.o main.o -o program
Graf.o: graf_struktura/Graf.cpp graf_struktura/Graf.h lifo/TabDyn.hpp lifo/Stos.hpp
    $(COMP) graf_struktura/Graf.cpp -o $@
wgraf.o: wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_graf.cpp wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_graf.h    graf_struktura/Graf.h lifo/Stos.hpp
    $(COMP) wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_graf.cpp -o $@
wnazwe.o: wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_nazwe_pliku.cpp    wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_nazwe_pliku.h wczytywanie_grafu/komunikaty.cpp 
    $(COMP) wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_nazwe_pliku.cpp -o $@
komunikaty.o: wczytywanie_grafu/komunikaty.cpp
    $(COMP) wczytywanie_grafu/komunikaty.cpp
menu.o: menu/menu.cpp graf_struktura/Graf.h
    $(COMP) menu/menu.cpp
main.o: main.cpp wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_nazwe_pliku.h    wczytywanie_grafu/wczytaj_graf.h menu/menu.cpp graf_struktura/Graf.h
    $(COMP) main.cpp
#Here is the issue.
Stos.o: lifo/Stos.hpp lifo/Stos.tpp lifo/TabDyn.hpp
    $(COMP) lifo/Stos.hpp -o $@
TabDyn.o: lifo/TabDyn.hpp lifo/TabDyn.tpp
    $(COMP) lifo/TabDyn.hpp -o $@
```

Compiler actually creates "Stos.o" but fails to include it in "program" producing quoted error.

Hope that now my issue is more clear. Sorry if makefile is not elegant. I'm still a beginner at makefiles, please be understanding.

Comment: Usually one puts template definitions in a `.inl` file (or some other ending), since `.cpp` implies that that file should be compiled directly, but one should not compile template definitions on their own.

Comment: Please show your makefile rules and explain what you're doing properly. At a guess I'd say you're compiling the .h, which with gcc produces a precompiled header. If you've called that precompiled header file MyClass.o (rather than the conventional MyClass.gch) then you'll confuse the linker trying to link it, because it's not a .o object file.

Comment: As I thought, you're compiling headers (and doing that with G++ produces precompiled headers, usually called .gch) but calling the output `.o`, then trying to link that into your main program, which can't work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your MyClass.h looks like

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
template<typename T>
  struct MyClass
  {
    void f();
  };
#include "MyClass.tcc"
#endif
```

And the MyClass.tcc file looks like

```
template<typename T>
  void
  MyClass::f(T)
  { }
```

Then code that uses the template, say in a file called main.cpp, looks like:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
  MyClass<int> m;
  m.f(1);
}
```

And the Makefile could look like:

```
main: main.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

main.o: main.cpp MyClass.h MyClass.tcc
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The makefile should **not** compile the template header, it compiles the main.cpp file into a .o, and lists the headers as dependencies. If either of the headers or `main.cpp` changes then `main.o` will be recompiled. Don't compile the headers though.

FWIW, in my own code I use `.cc` for source files, `.h` for headers and `.tcc` for inline definitions.  GCC knows that `.tcc` is a header file and will treat it correctly (as a header) if you say `g++ foo.tcc`, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html for the file extensions GCC recognises.

N.B. rather than manually listing all the header dependencies you can use GCC to produce makefile fragments listing the dependencies, e.g. for `main.cpp` you would generate a `main.d` and in the makefile do `include main.d` ... that's beyond the scope of this answer though.

Comment: It was exactly the case. However I've already changed the names as stated above, however arbitrarily. Please say explicitly, which names should I choose for the two of my files. "tcc" istead of "h", but what about the cpp one?

Comment: No, read more carefully, I've shown all the detail you should need. The header is called `.h` and the file it includes is called `.tcc`. But the problem is not the filenames, it's your broken makefile.

Comment: I think I've read it carefully, still I'm not sure what to do. You say I should not compile the template header. Instead you recommend compiling definitions (let it be *.tcc). But considering the thing I stated at the very beginning of my problem's description, my templates work in such way that the definitions are included into the header through #include directive at the end of the *.h file. Because of that if I do it your way, compiler has no idea as to member of which class do I define. Please explain me in more detail then what is the proper handling of such cases. Thank you.

Comment: I've renamed the definitions file in my example to .tcc, I don't know if that will help you follow the example

Comment: _ Instead you recommend compiling definitions (let it be *.tcc)._ No! Do not compile headers! Do not compile `.h`! Do not compile `.tcc`! Only compile the files that use the templates (in your example `Graf.cpp`, but **not** `Stos.hpp` or `Stos.tpp`). It shouldn't be difficult to follow my makefile example, it's only a few lines long!

Answer (score 1):

Include neither .h nor .cpp in your makefile. Files that use the template will include the .h (which will include the .cpp), and every translation unit will end up with (weak) symbols for all functions of the template without either of the files being in your Makefile.

Comment: But if I modify my template while all other files have remained the same since the last compilation and then try to use "make", the compiler won't start since the only file changed isn't included in the makefile, right? There must be the other way round then.

Comment: I don't know much about makefiles, but I'm pretty sure you're supposed to put each files dependancies in the makefile.

Comment: @MooingDuck : indeed, that's what I try to do. Makefiles otherwise would make no sense. The question is however "how" in this case.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't understand. I have an error, which I quoted, that kinda blocks any compiling whatsoever.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11541/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-anonymous-infoholic)