# Expected initializer before '<' token

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class myClass prototyped in a header file, and am implementing it in a .cpp file that is included at the end of the header file.  When I use the code:

```
template<typename T>
class myClass {
public:
    void myFunction(const T item);
};
```

in the header file and

```
template <class T>
void myClass<T>::myFunction(const T item)
{
//stuff
}
```

in the implementation file, I get the above error on line 2 of the implementation code.  I have used this same exact syntax in another program with successful compilation and correctly functioning results, so I am quite confused.  There are three different function definitions in the .cpp file and all have this same error on their respective lines.  I assume I am making a small error but I really can't seem to figure it out.

Help and explanation are very much appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is an SSCCE which has the same error:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
myClass<int> example;
example.myFunction(1);
return 0;
}
```

myClass.h

```
#include<iostream>

#ifndef MYCLASS_H_
#define MYCLASS_H_

template<typename T>
class myClass {
public:
    void myFunction(const T item);
};

#include "myClass.cpp"
#endif /* MYCLASS_H_ */
```

myClass.cpp

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void myClass<T>::myFunction(const T item)
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

and I am using Code::Blocks 10.05 with the GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you're showing. Please include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Usually that means you have an error in the lines before that code. Probably forgot a ; or something just before that.

Comment: Please post your exact errors. Otherwise, the answer by @bash.d is most promising at this point.

Comment: I am unable to add the implementation to the header file because the header file includes a reference to the implementation file right before the end of it's definition, and the header file is to remain read only.  I will post an SSCCE momentarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by removing the myClass.cpp from the build configuration.  Not sure why this was necessary, but it works perfectly now.

Comment: It probably works because the myClass.cpp is actually meant to be a header file and not a source file. According to my research templates (normally) should be defined in header files, but you can use this trick (#include myClass.cpp at the end of #include myClass.h)

Answer (score 1):

Put the implementation of the method in the header file (`.h`) too

The compiler needs to know details of implementation in translation unit.

Comment: I am unable to do this because the purpose of the program is, in part, for the header file is to remain untouched.

Comment: So, You have to include `.cpp` files. However it's disgusting.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to declare a template in an `.h` file and define it in a `.cpp` file. The compiler needs template declaration and definition in a single file in order to create the code. So if your compiler does not support `export` keyword it won't work. 
So you should not use different files for declaration and definition. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185954/implications-of-template-declaration-definition) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are instantiated on demand and given the complexities which would be induced in compiler design most of the compilers build a restriction to keep the template declaration and definition in one single file. If not so, template declaration on top of class and function definitions would create a pattern difficult for the compiler to detect a pattern and instantiate the template.

Similar question has been discussed on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36039/1654121), and explained on [Parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) (Read: **Templates and multiple-file projects** at the end of the article).

Hope this helps!

Vivek

Comment: the first solution in the first link is the method I used, placing an include to the implementation file in the header file.  It doesn't seem to work.  I know not why (which is the whole of my problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Keep implementation in `myClass.cpp` file is also possible. Apart from the implementation itself, you need to put declarations with specific types of `T`. For example, if `T` could be `int` and `float`, `myClass.cpp` should be like:

```cpp
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void myClass<T>::myFunction(const T item)
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
}

// Declarations with specific types.
template void myClass<int>::myFunction(const int item);
template void myClass<float>::myFunction(const float item);
```